# get_member_named() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@my_bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        server = discord.Server
        await my_bot.send_message(server.get_member_named('mystery#5137'), 'Hello')
```

Why didn't work?

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roman-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Roman-PC/Desktop/t1.py", line 11, in on_message
    await my_bot.send_message(server.get_member_named('name'), 'Hello')
TypeError: get_member_named() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a `discord.Server`, rather you should get the server from the `message` object as (see the [docs](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message) for `discord.Message`)

```
s = message.server
```

then you can

```
s.get_member_named('mystery#5137')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the Member with a name.
Instead of putting:

```py
server = discord.Server
await my_bot.send_message(server.get_member_named('mystery#5137'), 'Hello')
```

You need:

```py
server = message.server
await my_bot.send_message(server.get_member_named(name='mystery#5137'), 'Hello')
```